# Angular - Is it possible to refresh a controller, but not the HTML page

Tags: angularjs

Am new to Angular so not sure if this is actually possible - however is it possible to refresh/reload a controller, without refreshing the HTML page itself?

So in doing so any variables that are instantiated with the controller would be recalculated and simply updated in my view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is exactly what Angular is for - developing Single-Page Applications (SPAs). In fact, reloading a page is undesirable since you would lose all of your scope variables unless you are saving to/reading from cookies (or some other stateful solution).

Comment: Great. And to point me in the right direction how is this done - reloading controller without page refresh. Is it a line of code call?

Comment: Have you gone through any Angular tutorials? Start [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: Yes, I've built a basic app using multiple controllers, made services, a couple of custom directives and using ngRoute - however can't see anything to simply refresh a controller/one line. $route.reload still shows a very short refresh like effect

Comment: Is $route.reload() what you are looking for?